# Firebase push notification not updating text simultaneously

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app contains a textview, which i am trying to update using push notifications from firebase. It works fine, when the app is in foreground state, but, if app is in background state i only receive a notification and text does not get updated.

***My problem:-***

Suppose if my app is on screen, and a message is pushed from firebase, textview get's updated with no notification on notification tray. When app is in background state, i only receive a notification, textview does not get updated.

**What i want?**

Is it possible to update textview as well as receive a notification irrespective of app's state?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
private TextView txtRegId, txtMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtRegId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_reg_id);
    txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);

    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // gcm successfully registered
                // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                displayFirebaseRegId();

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
                    txtMessage.setText("New Message: " + message);
                else
                    txtMessage.setText("No new Updates!");
            }
        }
    };

    displayFirebaseRegId();

}

// Fetches reg id from shared preferences
// and displays on the screen
private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

    Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
        txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
    else
        txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // register GCM registration complete receiver
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

    // register new push message receiver
    // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

    // clear the notification area when the app is opened
    NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

**FirebaseMessagingService**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text and image
 */
private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with firebase but with the LocalBroadcastManager.
You are destroying your instance onPause and that happens when activity goes in background. So the message from firebase does not get to the Activity.Please change:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

This is called when activity gets destroyed but not when activity is in background

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Hope this helps,
Best!

Comment: Tried still same result :(